# Should a class contain a collection of itself?

Tags: c#

Is it poor design to have a class containing a collection of itself like in a List<> for C#? Why is this and what is a better approach and why?

EDIT: More specifically, I have a class called Product and a method in the class called GetProducts() that returns a List collection. It good be grabbing the products from a database, flat file, or xml... not sure yet.

Thanks!

Comment: OK, I have a class called product and a method inside called GetProducts that returns a List<Product> and I wasn't sure if this was the right approach.

Comment: I would perhaps consider writing a `ProductCollection` class which would provide collections related methods, but I wouldn't bother much about it. Perhaps making this `GetProducts` method static to your `Product` class is sufficient. This way, your `Product` class would behave somehow like a product façade, if we may say so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the Product and GetProducts() update I think this might not be such a good thing.

I use a rule of thumb kind of a principle here that relies on the logic that is domain, not language, specific. So in your case I would ask myself: "Does my product contain other actual products?" If the answer is yes then the collection of products is a perfectly legit thing to have in the Product class. If not ask what actually contains these products. A store maybe?

There is an exception to this rule with static methods. If GetProducts() is static then the upper reasoning does not apply and is usually perfectly fine to have it in the Product class.

Comment: +1 for explained approach. =)

Comment: why would the static method not apply in your example? just curious.

Comment: The way I view static methods for data models (what this sounds like it is) is that they use that they have something to do with that class but are up a level. I'm not sure I'm explaining this properly. I understand it in my head but writing it out is not as simple for me :) But for example Parse() methods are a typical thing. 'int.Parse(somestring)' is a static method and better then 'a.Parse(somestring)' (a gets the value parsed) because you can use it in an expression like 'int c = 24 + int.Parse(somestring)'. I hope I'm relying this properly.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd use the repository pattern:

```
public class IProductRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Product> GetAll();
}
```

Then write an implementation:

```
public class ProductRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        // Database logic or read from an xml file... etc.
    }
}
```

Pass an `IProductRepository` to the caller (using an IoC container like Ninject or Castle Windsor). Then, if necessary, you can easily mock `IProductRepository` for testing with the caller.

This way you're keeping the actual model (`Product`) separate from "what you can do" with products.

But, if `Product`s also needed to have `Products` (example: `SubProducts`), you could have an `ICollection<Product>` on `Product` as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine. You've come up with a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) or a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(data_structure))

Answer (score 0):

It might be both poor and good, depending on the problem you're solving, and if it is a generalized object or not. Many factors may influence such design decisions. In the end, it is no matter of good or bad design, but if this is the right path you're choosing to cross the river.

**EDIT #1**

> OK, I have a class called product and a method inside called GetProducts that returns a List and I wasn't sure if this was the right approach.

Under this circumstance, I would make the `Product.GetProducts` method static. As such, when you want to load the products, you will simply address your `Product` class like so:

```
IList<Product> products = Product.GetProducts();
```

A list of itself would assume that a product might be composed of different other products, like those component products. But, with a static method, it would more admittedly make your `Product` class the factory for product related business.

Comment: Are you talking about the factory pattern here or just in general as the object that creates products?

Answer (score 0):

Sure that's generally fine. That's generally the sensible way of implementing a tree in an OOP-y way; a `TreeNode` has to contain a `List<TreeNode> m_Children` field in it so the node knows what it's children are for tree traversal.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it does not conflict with single responsibility principal I suppose it would not be a problem.